# Can I get a dump of all my databases *except one* using mysqldump?

Tags: windows, backup, mysql

I'm currently using mySQLdump to backup my dev machine and servers.

There is one project I just started, however, that has a HUUUUUGE database that I don't really need backed up, and i'll be a big problem to add it to the rest of the backup cycle.

I'm currently doing this:

```
"c:\Program Files\mysql\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqldump" -u root -pxxxxxx --all-databases > g:\backups\MySQL\mysqlbackup.sql
```

Is it possible to somehow specify "except this database(s)"?

I wouldn't like to have to specify the list of DBs manually, since that would mean that I'd have to remember updating my backup batch file every time I create a new DB, and I know that's not gonna happen.

EDIT: As you probably guessed from my command line above, i'm doing this on Windows, so I can't do any kind of fancy bash stuff, only wimpy .bat things.

Alternatively, if you have other ideas to solve this same issue, they are more than welcome, of course!

Comment: Maybe this should be a feature request to Oracle.

Comment: If your using Windows maybe look into doing it with PowerShell

Answer (score 31):

`mysql ... -N -e "show databases like '%';" |`[`grep`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)`-v -F databaseidontwant |`[`xargs`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm)`mysqldump ... --databases > out.sql`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unforunately, i'm on Windows, so I can't do that

Comment: @Daniel: You *did* click on the links in the answer... right?

Comment: Duh, no, I didn't. Those didn't really look like links to me, at all. I blame the site's designer :-)

Thanks for the asnwer!

Answer (score 30):

```
echo 'show databases;' | mysql -uroot -proot | grep -v ^Database$ | grep -v ^information_schema$ | grep -v ^mysql$ | grep -v -F db1 | xargs mysqldump -uroot -proot  --databases > all.sql
```

dumps all databases except: `mysql`, `information_schema`, `mysql` and `db1`.

Or if you'd like to review the list before dumping:

1. `echo 'show databases;' | mysql -uroot -proot > databases.txt`
2. edit `databases.txt` and remove any you don't want to dump
3. `cat databases.txt | xargs mysqldump -uroot -proot --databases > all.sql`

Comment: This is awesome! It's really the most elegant solution that's out there! and I am also including Linux machines when I make that statement.

Comment: Exact syntax used for linux: 1. echo 'show databases;' | mysql -u root -p > databases.txt 2. nano databases.txt 3. cat databases.txt | xargs mysqldump -u root -p --databases > all.sql

Answer (score 10):

What about

> --ignore-table=db_name.tbl_name
>
> Do not dump the given table, which must be specified using both the database and table names. To ignore multiple tables, use this option multiple times.

Maybe you'll need to specify a few to completely ignore the big database.

Comment: Maybe, but this DB has about 100 tables, that'll be a pain :-)
Still the simplest idea, though, thanks!

Comment: Good point. But still, enough tables that it's a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 7):

I created the following one line solution avoiding multiple grep commands.

```
mysql -e "show databases;" | grep -Ev "Database|DatabaseToExclude1|DatabaseToExclude2" | xargs mysqldump --databases >mysql_dump_filename.sql
```

The -E in grep enables extended regex support which allowed to provide different matches separated by the pipe symbol "|". More options can be added to the mysqldump command. But only before the "--databases" parameter.

Little side note, i like to define the filename for the dump like this ...

```
... >mysql_dump_$(hostname)_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M).sql
```

This will automatically ad the host name, date and time to the filename. :)

Answer (score 4):

Seeing as your using Windows you should have PowerShell available to use.
Here is a short PowerShell script to get a list of all Databases, remove unwanted ones from the list & then use mysqldump to backup the others.

```powershell
$MySQLPath = "."
$Hostname = "localhost"
$Username = "root"
$Password = ""

# Get list of Databases
$Databases = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]] (
    & $MySQLPath\mysql.exe -h"$Hostname" -u"$Username" -p"$Password" -B -N -e"show databases;"
)

# Remove databases from list we don't want
[void]$Databases.Remove("information_schema")
[void]$Databases.Remove("mysql")

# Dump database to .SQL file
& $MySQLPath\mysqldump.exe -h"$HostName" -u"$Username" -p"$Password" -B $($Databases) | Out-File "DBBackup.sql"
```

Comment: this is the simpliest way to do it on windows IMO

Comment: This worked perfectly for us too, the only catch was that you need to have PowerShell 3.0 to run this.

Comment: I strongly adwise to change last line to ("| Out-File" to "-r") as
& $MySQLPath\mysqldump.exe -h"$HostName" -u"$Username" -p"$Password" -B $($Databases) -r "DBBackup.sql"
Otherwise you will lost some special characters and your dump size will be twice.
Also checking databases before proceed might be interesting

Write-Host "Will take backup of..."
$Databases -join "`r`n" | Out-String 
Write-Host "If it is ok ?"
Write-Host "Press any key to continue..."
[void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true)

Answer (score 3):

Create a backup user and only grant that user access to the databases that you want to backup.

You still need to remember to explicitly grant the privileges but that can be done in the database and doesn't require a file to be edited.

Comment: thank you for that idea!
The *remembering* part is the problem, though. Is it possible to give a user access to all databases by default, and only DENY access to some?
That way, when creating a new DB, it'll get backup up, but I can choose explicitly some to skip.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot default to allow access and then explicity deny access to certain databases.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a lot of finagling to come up with this but I've used it for a few years now and it works well...

```
mysql -hServerName -uUserName -pPassword -e "SELECT CONCAT('\nmysqldump -hServerName -uUserName -pPassword --set-gtid-purged=OFF --max_allowed_packet=2048M --single-transaction --add-drop-database --opt --routines --databases ',DBList,' | mysql -hServerName2 -uUserName2 -pPAssword2 ' ) AS Cmd FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(schema_name SEPARATOR ' ') AS DBList FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE LEFT(schema_name, 8) <> 'cclegacy' AND schema_name NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema','test','external','othertoskip')) a \G" | cmd
```

Instead of the pipe over to mysql where I'm moving from serverName to Servername2 you could redirect to a file but this allows me to tailor what I move. Sometimes i even OR the list so I can say LIKE 'Prefix%' etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one for production
It excludes `'performance_schema\|information_schema\|mysql\|sys'`...modify for your needs

```
MYSQL_USER=
MYSQL_PASS=
MYSQL_HOST=
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS} -h${MYSQL_HOST}"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--routines --triggers --single-transaction"

DBLIST=`mysql -s --host=$MYSQL_HOST --user=$MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASS \
--execute="SHOW DATABASES;" | grep -v \
'performance_schema\|information_schema\|mysql\|sys' | awk '{printf("%s ",$0)}'`

mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --databases ${DBLIST} | gzip >all-dbs.sql.gz
```

Comment: You may have an error in `awk '{printf("\"%s\" ",$0)}` the command returns `mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database '"<1st database name>"' when selecting the database`. Removing \" ... \" works

Comment: @ZalemCitizen updated answer. thanks.