# Backing up MySql while excluding certain databases with batch file and I'm running into problems

Tags: mysql, batch-file, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to backup my MySql databases on Windows 2012 via a batch file.

This is what I have:

```
    %mysql% -u %USER% -p%PASSWORD% -B -s -e"show databases" > %backupdir%\mysqldblist.tmp

    FOR /F %%D IN (%backupdir%\mysqldblist.tmp) DO (
        set DONTBACKUP=NOTHING
        ECHO Creating backup for database ''%%D''
        if [%%D]==[information_schema] set DONTBACKUP=TRUE
        if [%%D]==[mysql] set DONTBACKUP=TRUE
        if [%%D]==[performance_schema] set DONTBACKUP=TRUE
        if [%%D]==[test] set DONTBACKUP=TRUE
        PAUSE
        IF [%DONTBACKUP%]==[TRUE] %mysqldump% -u %USER% -p%PASSWORD% --result-file="%backupdir%%%D_%mydate%.sql" "%%D" 
        PAUSE
    )
```

I'm trying to exclude the databases such as mysql, performance_schema, and test but it is exiting after the **first iteration**. I figured I'd just set a variable and check it if it was a certain database but it's just not happening, first check it exits.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here?

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

This is what I see in the command prompt window, if it helps:

```
ECHO Creating backup for database '%D'
if [%D] == [information_schema] set DONTBACKUP=TRUE
if [%D] == [mysql] set DONTBACKUP=TRUE
if [%D] == [performance_schema] set DONTBACKUP=TRUE
if [%D] == [test] set DONTBACKUP=TRUE
PAUSE
IF [] == [TRUE] "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump"...
```

I see something is not right, I'm trying to debug it now, but I do not see it right off. I'm not sure why %%D or why DONTBACKUP isn't being populated...

**ADDITIONAL INFO #2**

This is where I think I am failing:

```
 if [information_schema] == [information_schema] set DONTBACKUP=TRUE
```

It isn't being set to TRUE so it tries to do the backup. I'm not sure what I'm overlooking, but why would this comparison fail?

Comment: try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917485/can-i-get-a-dump-of-all-my-databases-except-one-using-mysqldump there's a solution using windows powershell down the bottom

Comment: From what you describe, I am quite confident that `%backupdir%\mysqldblist.tmp` is actually an empty file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of the file add this line:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

In the for loop, when looking at value of `DONTBACKUP`, use `!DONTBACKUP!`.
Also, going by the logic, the check for `DONTBACKUP` should be inverted.

So here is the modified file:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
%mysql% -u %USER% -p%PASSWORD% -B -s -e"show databases" > %backupdir%\mysqldblist.tmp

FOR /F %%D IN (%backupdir%\mysqldblist.tmp) DO (
    set DONTBACKUP=NOTHING
    ECHO Creating backup for database ''%%D''
    if [%%D]==[information_schema] set DONTBACKUP=TRUE
    if [%%D]==[mysql] set DONTBACKUP=TRUE
    if [%%D]==[performance_schema] set DONTBACKUP=TRUE
    if [%%D]==[test] set DONTBACKUP=TRUE
    PAUSE
    IF not [!DONTBACKUP!]==[TRUE] %mysqldump% -u %USER% -p%PASSWORD% --result-file="%backupdir%%%D_%mydate%.sql" "%%D" 
    PAUSE
)
```